# UICollectionView - Image is getting set randomly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collectionView in my App. I am setting image for the cell backgroundView in didSelect delegate. But When i select one cell indexPath the image is getting set for 3 cell indexPath. When i scroll the collectionView the images are getting changed randomly? Please Help me. thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:uio];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:       (NSInteger)section
{
     return 50;
}

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:uio
 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    NSLog(@"index %@",indexPath);
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpg"]];

 }
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: please show your cellForItemAtIndexPath() method

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to tell, but my guess is that cells are being reused as you scroll.

Comment: I have added my source code.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you reuse your cell. An option would be to have an dictionary variable to say that your cell has been selected and reset the image if it has not been.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"index %@",indexPath);
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpg"]];

    [selectedDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Then in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method you would check that value

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:uio
 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL selected = [[selectedDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]] boolValue];

    if(selected){
        cell.backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpg"]];
    }else{
        cell.backgroundView = nil;
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   return cell;
}
```

Of course if you use some kind of object as model, it would appropriate to have a selected variable in here, you won't need a nsdictionary any more.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

When you scroll `UICollectionview` then cell are reused that is problem 
add `Collectionview` inside `scrollview`.

Try this Inside:

Scroll_View  is Your Scroll View

collection is Your Collectionview

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.Scroll_View.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, collectionView.contentSize.height);
    CGRect fram_For_Collection_View = self.collection_view.frame;
    fram_For_Collection_View.size.height = collectionView.contentSize.height;
    self.collection.view.frame = fram_For_Collection_View;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtPath:` is adding a new image view to the cell. Nothing is removing that image view when the cell is reused. So, when you say:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:uio
```

forIndexPath:indexPath];

in your `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, you're may get back some cell that already has one or more image views.

My suggestion would be to add the image view to the cell in the cell prototype, perhaps in your storyboard or in the cell's initializer. Have your `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` set the image for that image view to the correct image for the given path.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that UICollectionView reuses cells. So in didSelectItemAtIndexPath: you set the cell background, but then the UICollectionView reuses that same cell as needed (and you're not resetting the cell.backgroundView in cellForItemAtIndexPath:).

The way to fix this is to maintain an NSIndexSet of selected cells. In didSelectItemAtIndexPath: you can add the index of the item that was selected, and then force a reload of that item by calling reloadItemsAtIndexPaths. Then, in your cellForItemAtIndexPath: check the index set to see if the selected index is included, and if so, set the backgroundView of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few days ago & I posted a question here. Here is the answer I got & it works for me.

[Collection View Cell multiple item select Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958393/collection-view-cell-multiple-item-select-error)

And also if you are using a custom cell you can add this code to the `init` method of that cell & it will work too.

```
        CGFloat borderWidth = 6.0f;
        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        bgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        bgView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        self.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```